# How to append dropdown item text in the button text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append the value of the dropdowm menu item in the text "Sorted by"?

I want to show in the button text something like this:

*Sorted by: Highest positive votes*  or *Sorted by: Alphabetic* according to the dropdown item selected.

```
       <div class="btn-group float-right">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span>Sorted By</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu item-sorted" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='thumbsUp'>Highest positive votes</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='thumbsDown'>Highest negative votes</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='comments'>Highest comments</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='alphabetic'>Alphabetic</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your current code, showing what you've tried that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this with jquery:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').onClick(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('#dropdownMenuButton span').text( "Sorted By: " + text);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If the selected dropdown option is marked by a `selected="true"` attribute, for example, you can get it like so:

```
$("#dropdownMenuButton span").html("Sorted By " + $('dropdown-menu[aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink"] a.dropdown-item[selected="true"]').text());
```

Please keep in mind that this will not be triggered on an event click. To do it on an event click:

```
$("div.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item").click(function(e){
    $("#dropdownMenuButton span").html("Sorted By " + $(this).text()); // gets the selection text and puts it in the button
    $(this).parent().find("a.dropdown-item[selected=true]").attr("selected", null); // unselects previous selections
    $(this).attr("selected", "true"); // selects the current one 
});
```

This attaches a listener to all anchor elements with a class `dropdown-item` that are children to any div with a `dropdown-menu` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. All you need to do is add a span with the class `.option` to your html and this small part of jquery which checks for when you click on your dropdown and adds said elements text to your button:

```js
$('.dropdown-item').click(function() { // When dropdown is clicked:
  $(".option").text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group float-right">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span>Sorted By <span class="option"></span></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu item-sorted" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='thumbsUp'>Highest positive votes</a><br/>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='thumbsDown'>Highest negative votes</a><br />
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='comments'>Highest comments</a><br />
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='alphabetic'>Alphabetic</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following

- Add an element that will show the sorted by text
- Add click event listeners

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-item").forEach((el) => {
  el.onclick = (ev) => document.getElementById("sorted-by").textContent = ev.currentTarget.textContent;
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group float-right">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span>Sorted By <span id="sorted-by"></span></span>
            </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu item-sorted" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='thumbsUp'>Highest positive votes</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='thumbsDown'>Highest negative votes</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='comments'>Highest comments</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="datesort" name='alphabetic'>Alphabetic</a>
  </div>
</div>
```